# What does this C# snippet mean?

Tags: c#

```
struct MyStruct : int
{
   .../...
}
```

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states that after the `:` is the list of the implemented interfaces, but `int`is quite a curious interface to me...

Is it maybe a way to define the size of the struct? Someting like a bitfield?

Comment: `enum`s allow a similar construct, but I don't think it's legal for `struct`s. Where did you find this snippet?

Comment: This is snippet of bad code that won't compile. It does not mean anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is illegal and means nothing whatsoever.

> Error 5   Type 'int' in interface list is not an interface    redacted\Program.cs 13  23  ConsoleApplication9

However! If by `int` you mean "an interface", then it means: "this is a value-type that implements an interface"

You can't, however, have an interface called `int`, since `int` is a reserved keyword. You would have to refer to that as `@int` in the C#.

Comment: @ShadowWizard `public interface @int {}` is an interface "called"  `int` - but you'd need to use `struct MyStruct : @int` in the C#

Answer (score 0):

here `struct MyStruct : int` is not an interface so complier will fail this

If you have Resharper it will warn you by underlining it red before even running the build

For knowledge int is an Alias of [System.Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) and it is a structure

Comment: can you please explain what's wrong with the answer so I can correct it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Struct should actually say Enum, then it'd make some sense.